# Logout other users from KDE/plasma as root

Tags: scripting, kde, root, plasma, logout

I'd like to be able to automatically log out users from their KDE/plasma sessions by a script running as root. The log-out should happen "gracefully", i. e. applications should get a chance to shut down properly -- like when I hit the "Logout" entry from the application launcher.
The usually recommended `qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout <x> <y> <z>` doesn't work, it gives me a `Could not connect to dbus server: org.freedesktop.dbus.Error.AccessDenied: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/0/bus: Permission denied` error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out:

```
su -c "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/<numerical-user-id>/bus qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 3 2" "<username>"
```